# This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7110/Home/ShowSearchForm HTTP ERROR 404

Tags: c#

```
public class JokersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly WebApplicationElmiDbContext _context;

    public JokersController(WebApplicationElmiDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Jokers
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return _context.Joker != null ?
                    View(await _context.Joker.ToListAsync()) :
                    Problem("Entity set 'WebApplicationElmDbiContext.Joker'  is null.");



    }
    // GET: Jokers/ShowSearchForm
    public async Task<IActionResult> ShowSearchForm()
    {
        return _context.Joker != null ?
                    View() :
                    Problem("Entity set 'WebApplicationElmDbiContext.Joker'  is null.");



    }
```

This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7110/Home/ShowSearchForm HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: The controller name is `Jokers` instead of `Home` in your code, SO why you use `Home/ShowSearchForm`?

Comment: Good question, let me review my codes one more time. Thanks.

Comment: Xinran, As you said, I went back and checked my codes, fixed it, and it worked. thanks.